# How to enable editing for a single column in Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Right now, I have three columns in a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProjectTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="PopulateProjectTable">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectID" HeaderText="Project ID" SortExpression="ProjectID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectDescription" HeaderText="Project Description" SortExpression="ProjectDescription" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectNotes" HeaderText="Project Notes" SortExpression="ProjectNotes" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="PopulateProjectTable" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sandboxConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Projects]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

For the most part, it's read only except for the third column. At first, I thought about using `AutoGenerateEditButton`, but it causes every column to be writable. I thought that would be fine, but I don't want to give user that much power. Therefore, I thought of two ways to tackle this problem. The first way was to have it such that the third column would be readable by default, but by left clicking a row in that column, it would change it to be writable. It would be reminiscent of lightly double clicking a file name in Windows and it would be editable.

The second way is to disable the editing for the first two columns when I hit the `AutoGenerateEditButton` and to instead only have it "work" for the third column. However, I'm unsure of how to do this part.

Is my first way even possible in GridView? Note that I am doing all of this in Visual Studio. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the design mode for the .aspx file.

Click on your GridView control.

Click the small ">" arrow button that appears.

Click Edit Columns.

In the selected fields list, you can set the attributes for each column.

Make a column editable by setting readOnly to false.

Comment: Also, you must enable the 'edit' functionality for the gridview:
Go to the design mode for the .aspx file.

Click on your GridView control.

Click the small ">" arrow button that appears.

Click Enable Editing.

Answer (score 0):

In the onRowDataBound event for the grid, you can set the columns you want disabled on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will need to use Edit template>> it will allow you to make cell editable or read only